# error while accessing contact "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.configuration.step.StepArtifacts"

Tags: web8.5, audience-manager

We are using SDL web 8.5 while initializing contact we are getting below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.configuration.step.StepArtifacts
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
com.tridion.storage.AudienceManagerProfileDAO.getInstance(AudienceManagerProfileDAO.java:23)
com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ExtendedDetailsDal.loadExtendedDetails(ExtendedDetailsDal.java:29)
com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ExtendedDetails.loadExtendedDetailsTemplate(ExtendedDetails.java:37)
com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ExtendedDetails.<init>(ExtendedDetails.java:61)
com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.init(Contact.java:867)
com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:753)
com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:736)
org.apache.jsp.test_002dcontact_jsp._jspService(test_002dcontact_jsp.java:123)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
```

it seems some jar file is missing but we are no able to figure out that jar file

**Update**

Code snippet

```
String email = "test@gmail.com";
            com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact contact;
            try {
                contact = new com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact(new String[]{email, "website"});
                out.println("Contact - " + contact + "<br>");
            } catch (com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ContactDoesNotExistException cdne) {
                out.println("Error1 - " + email + "<br>");
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps list the JARs you do have and it could be as simple as someone confirming the list (and possibly versions) they have?

It would also be useful if you could include, just to confirm, your code snippet.

Comment: You can check The dependency tree of your project by following command - `mvn dependency:tree`. This will only list the information about the dependencies listed in your `pom.xml` More on it [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

Comment: @Velmurugan we have checked but there is no such class exist it seems some other issue

Answer (score 1):

That class last existed in 2013 SP1 (in cd_core.jar), so it looks like you've got some old files in your web application / services.

You don't mention this being an upgrade, but I assume so. Otherwise, you've gotten some old installation files from 2013 instead of Web 8.5.

You should do an inventory of the files you've installed and make sure there is nothing old in there (or just do a clean install)